# Importing plugins from Eclipse manifest file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I want to develop an Eclipse plugin with IntelliJ.
To get all the dependencies, I created the project in Eclipse and cloned the code to IntelliJ.

The Eclipse project created a manifest file that contains the following:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jface,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 com.sap.adt.tools.abapsource.ui,
 com.sap.adt.util.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.7.800",
 com.abapblog.adt.quickfix;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.11.0",
 org.eclipse.wst.json.core,
 org.eclipse.wst.json.schemaprocessor,
 org.eclipse.wst.json.ui;bundle-version="1.0.600",
 org.junit,
 org.junit.jupiter.api
```

is there a way to import those inside of IntelliJ?

Comment: Good luck trying to drive a screw with a sledgehammer. You're not the first one wasting time trying to do so. ;)

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins use the OSGi MANIFEST.MF to specify plug-in dependencies, you can only really develop them on something that understands that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with an IntelliJ plugin called "Eclipser".

Official IntelliJ documentation recommends it:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html#CodeFormatting

It basically helps you migrate your settings from Eclipse to IntelliJ. You can get it here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7153-eclipser/

Comment: The question is about developing Eclipse plug-ins which require a lot of specialist support as they do things like plug-in dependencies using the OSGi system.